# UserControl inside of a Repeater inside of an UpdatePanel... How do I get the button OnClick to fire inside of the UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is code in my aspx page...

```
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="WorkItemPanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
       <table class="WorkItemTable">
       <tr>
           <th class="WorkItemTable" style="background-color: #eeeeee; width: 170px;"><div style="font-weight: bold; width: 170px; padding: 5px;" id="createpb" runat="server">Product Backlog</div>
                <div id="createpbMenu" class="ContextMenuPanel" style="display: none" runat="server">
                    <UC:CreateProductBacklogMenu ID="CreateProductBacklogMenu" runat="server"></UC:CreateProductBacklogMenu>
                </div>
                <ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender runat="server" ID="DDE"
                    TargetControlID="createpb" 
                    DropDownControlID="createpbMenu" />
           </th>
           <th class="WorkItemTable" style="width:50%;"><b>Not Done</b></td>
           <th class="WorkItemTable" style="width: 158px;"><div style="width: 158px;"><b>In Progress</b></div></td>
           <th class="WorkItemTable" style="width: 158px;"><div style="width: 158px;"><b>Ready For Test</b></div></td>
           <th class="WorkItemTable" style="width:50%;"><b>Done</b></td>
       </tr>
       <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="productBacklog" EnableViewState="false">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
            <td class="WorkItemTable" valign="top" style="width: 170px;height: 100%">
                <UC:ProductBacklogView onSomethingButtonClick="" id="pbv" PB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:ProductBacklogView>
            </td>
            <td class="WorkItemTable DropTarget State-NotDone" valign="top" style="width:50%;">
                <asp:Repeater DataSource=<%#GetStatus(Eval("ID"),"Not Done")%> runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <UC:WorkItemView CssClass=<%#GetWorkItemCssClass(Container.DataItem)%> ID="WorkItemView1" SB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:WorkItemView>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
           <td class="WorkItemTable DropTarget State-InProgress" valign="top" style="width: 158px;">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" DataSource=<%#GetStatus(Eval("ID"),"In Progress")%> runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <UC:WorkItemView CssClass=<%#GetWorkItemCssClass(Container.DataItem)%> ID="WorkItemView1" SB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:WorkItemView>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
           </td>
            <td class="WorkItemTable DropTarget State-ReadyForTest" valign="top" style="width: 158px;">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater4" DataSource=<%#GetStatus(Eval("ID"),"Ready For Test")%> runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <UC:WorkItemView CssClass=<%#GetWorkItemCssClass(Container.DataItem)%> ID="WorkItemView1" SB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:WorkItemView>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
           </td>
           <td class="WorkItemTable DropTarget State-Done" style="width:50%;" valign="top">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" DataSource=<%#GetStatus(Eval("ID"),"Done")%> runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <UC:WorkItemView CssClass=<%#GetWorkItemCssClass(Container.DataItem)%> ID="WorkItemView1" SB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:WorkItemView>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
           </td>
           </tr>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <AlternatingItemTemplate>
         <tr style="background-color: #F6F6F6;">
            <td class="WorkItemTable" valign="top" style="width: 170px;">
              <UC:ProductBacklogView ID="ProductBacklogView1" PB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:ProductBacklogView>
            </td>
            <td class="WorkItemTable DropTarget State-NotDone" valign="top" style="width:50%;">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" DataSource=<%#GetStatus(Eval("ID"),"Not Done")%> runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <UC:WorkItemView CssClass=<%#GetWorkItemCssClass(Container.DataItem)%> ID="WorkItemView1" SB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:WorkItemView>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
           <td class="WorkItemTable DropTarget State-InProgress" valign="top" style="width: 158px;">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" DataSource=<%#GetStatus(Eval("ID"),"In Progress")%> runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <UC:WorkItemView CssClass=<%#GetWorkItemCssClass(Container.DataItem)%> ID="WorkItemView1" SB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:WorkItemView>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
           </td>
            <td class="WorkItemTable DropTarget State-ReadyForTest" valign="top" style="width: 158px;">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater4" DataSource=<%#GetStatus(Eval("ID"),"Ready For Test")%> runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                      <UC:WorkItemView CssClass=<%#GetWorkItemCssClass(Container.DataItem)%> ID="WorkItemView1" SB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:WorkItemView>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
           </td>
           <td class="WorkItemTable DropTarget State-Done" style="width:50%;" valign="top">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" DataSource=<%#GetStatus(Eval("ID"),"Done")%> runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <UC:WorkItemView CssClass=<%#GetWorkItemCssClass(Container.DataItem)%> ID="WorkItemView1" SB=<%# Container.DataItem %> runat="server"></UC:WorkItemView>
               </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
           </td>
         </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        </table>
   </ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="viewSprintButton" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My UserControl is ProductBacklogView (which exists inside the repeater). I tried to do something like this in the aspx...

```
        productBacklog.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler(productBacklog_BindAddButton);

        DataBind();           
    }


    void productBacklog_BindAddButton(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        if (e.Item.FindControl("ProductBacklogView1") != null)
        {
            btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("ProductBacklogView1").FindControl("patchBuildButton");
        }
        else
        {
            btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("pbv").FindControl("patchBuildButton");
        }


        if (btn != null)
        {
            ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btn); 
        }
    }
```

I fear that since the repeater has enableviewstate set to false, that it's not actually firing OnClick for the button. I'm kind of a noob so I'm not really sure what's going on. Any help to get the button inside of the ProductBacklogView control would be much helpful.
The Markup for the control is...

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProductBacklogView.ascx.cs" Inherits="ScrumDashboard.ui.ProductBacklogView" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/ui/ProductBacklogMenu.ascx"  TagName="ProductBacklogMenu" TagPrefix="UC" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<a id="<%="PBI_" + PB.Id.ToString()%>" />
<div id="pbMenu" class="ContextMenuPanel" style="display: none" runat="server">
    <UC:ProductBacklogMenu PB=<%# PB %> runat="server"></UC:ProductBacklogMenu>
</div>

<ajaxToolkit:DropDownExtender runat="server" ID="DDE"
    TargetControlID="pbView"
    DropDownControlID="pbMenu" />

<div id="pbView" class="ProductBacklogTitle" runat="server">
<a class="<%#PB.State=="Done" ? "DoneProductBacklog" : "NotDoneProductBacklog" %>" href="javascript: openWorkItemWithRefresh(<%#PB.Id%>, <%#PB.RevisionId%>, <%#IsTFS2012%>)"><%#PB.Title%></a> (<%#PB.Id%>)
</div>

<% if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(PB.Team) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentTeam)){%>
<div class="ProductBacklogText">Team:</div><div class="ProductBacklogText2"><%=PB.Team%></div>
<%}%>
<div class="ProductBacklogText">State:</div><div class="ProductBacklogText2"><%=PB.State%></div>
<div class="ProductBacklogText">Priority:</div><div class="ProductBacklogText2"><%=PB.BusinessPriority %></div>
<div class="ProductBacklogText">Effort:</div><div class="ProductBacklogText2"><%=PB.EstimatedEffort %></div>
<div class="ProductBacklogText">Work:</div><div class="ProductBacklogText2"><%=PB.All.CompletedWorkTotal + " of " + PB.All.WorkTotal + " (" + PB.All.CompletedWorkPercentage.ToString("##0") + "%)" + RenderWorkBreakdownChevrons()%></div>
<asp:Button id="patchBuildButton" Text="Build Patch" runat="server" OnClick="patchBuildButton_click" /><br />
<%=RenderWorkBreakdownInformation()%>
<div class="<%#ShowEstimateInformation ? "ProductBacklogText" : "ProductBacklogText invisible"%>">Est:</div><div class="<%#ShowEstimateInformation ? "ProductBacklogText2" : "ProductBacklogText2 invisible"%>"><%# RenderEstimate() %></div>
<%=RenderDefectInfo()%>
<%if(PB.SprintNumber!=CurrentSprint){%>
<div class="FromAnotherSprint">
<%=PB.SprintName%>

</div>
<%}%>
```

Comment: Can you show the markup for the usercontrol?

Comment: Added it in the post above.